# Sumar una columna varias veces con distintas condiciones

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en postgres y me gustaría que me ayuden a sumar una columna varias veces con distintas condiciones por ejemplo
tengo mi columna dias que son atrasos de creditos y la columna capital que genera un credito, necesito agruparlos como el cuadro donde estan agrupados por mayor a X dias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select 

case
when bpatra > 30  then 'MAYOR A 30'
when bpatra > 60  then 'MAYOR A 60'
when bpatra > 90  then 'MAYOR A 90'
when bpatra > 150  then 'MAYOR A 150'
when bpatra > 180  then 'MAYOR A 180'
when bpatra > 270  then 'MAYOR A 270'
else null end as tramos,

round(sum(bpsalp + bpsali -bpadev -bpsusp))as riesgo,
round(((sum(bpsalp + bpsali -bpadev -bpsusp)/b.riesgototal)*100),2)



from
fsd012co,
(select sum(bpsalp + bpsali -bpadev -bpsusp) riesgototal from fsd012co where bpfec = current_date and bptip <> 'P' And bpmon = 6900) b


where
(bpfec = current_date)and
(bpmon = 6900) and
(bptip <>'P' )

group by
tramos,
b.riesgototal

order by
tramos
```

Comment: ambas columnas de la izquierda es una tabla, y de esa tabla necesito hacer la suma por grupos  que se muestra a la derecha, me explico?

Comment: Por favor comparte el SQL que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: ahi compartí amigo abajo de la imagen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a tomar tu ejemplo simplificado para ilustrar cómo se puede hacer.

La idea es usar una expresión `CASE`. Pero cuidado, que el orden de las condiciones es importante. Las condiciones para cantidades más altas deben aparecer primero. De lo contrario, casi todas las cantidades van a ser sumadas bajo `dias > 30`.

Adicionalmente, en vez de traducir las condiciones del `CASE` directamente a texto, lo traduzco a un `ID` lógico que se puede usar luego para el `ORDER BY`:

```
select case tramo_id
            when 1 then 'vigentes'
            when 2 then 'MAYOR A 30'
            when 3 then 'MAYOR A 60'
            when 4 then 'MAYOR A 90'
            when 5 then 'MAYOR A 120'
       end as tramos,
       sum_capital
  from (select case when dias > 120 then 5
                    when dias > 90  then 4
                    when dias > 60  then 3
                    when dias > 30  then 2
                                    else 1
               end as tramo_id,
               sum(capital) as sum_capital
          from tbl
         group by tramo_id) t
 order by tramo_id
```

Comment: GENIO! MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!!  SALIO COMO QUIERO

Comment: UNA COSA MAS QUE SE ME OCURRE ES SUMAR LOS MONTOS DE >30>60>90>120 EL RESULTADO SERIA 79.000.000 LUEGO SUMAR >60>90>120